# How can I save file names with consecutive numbers when saving multiple txt files in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I have about 2000 pieces of data that are 7611 * 1 in size. And I want to save each data as a txt file. I want to save the txt file name in 1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt ... format, what should I do?

And additionally, when saving data, I want to keep it in 7611 * 1 format, what should I do? In this part, I will attach the code I wrote which is not work normally..
Please help.  Thank you.

```
    st = data which size is 7611*1

    for i = 1:2000

    data = fopen('%d.txt','w',i);   % The next code doesn't work. I wrote this code 
                                    % to tell you what form I want. 

    fprintf(data,'%d \n',st);       % I want to save as a column vector, but when I 
                                    % run it with the code next to it, the broken 
                                    % txt file is saved... I cant find reason..

    end
```

Comment: I hope you have a `fclose(data)` statement in your code otherwise the files are left open ...

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the `sprintf` command inside your for loop to create the file name, i.e.,

```
 for i = 1:2000
    fName = sprintf('%0.0f.txt',i)  % create file name
    data = fopen(fName,'w', ... );  % include additional specifications as needed
    fprintf( ... ) %  include specifications as needed
 end
```